# Security certificate does not appear in IIS after insertion

Tags: iis, ssl, ssl-certificate, mmc

I've created a self-signed certificate and import it with private key into Personal/Certificates folder like shown on the picture below:

[image]

When I want to use as.local certificate from IIS Manager it simple does not appear in the drop down list.

[image]

Does someone knows where's the problem?

Comment: Put the certificate also to Trusted Root authorities store. Then reopen IIS manager.

Answer (score -1):

Import the certificate with private key using IIS manager (Server Certificates). [Tutorial here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732785%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).